# Change tomcat web app datetime without changing OS datetime?

Tags: datetime, tomcat, time, server

I am going to demo a project, I need to change the system date time to a future time point to simulate the operation of a `Scheduler` module which changes status when the day comes.

I tried to change the OS date time, the web app worked but I have to face with  problems like:

- All my internet account cookies expired, I have to login again (which will makes my demo a bit longer)
- Some softwares license on my computer expired and I am unable to use it (I have to use those softwares during the demo)

I thought about using a VPS to run the web app but VPSs are expensive and I want the connection speed to be locally fast.

I want to ask if there is any other easy way to do it, like edit a config variable in tomcat setting or using a "Tomcat time changer" software?

I am sorry if this question is not fit for SO, if so could you (the moderators) migrate it to somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like I have to setup a virtual machine.

Comment: Dont change the system time, set the scheduler to an earlier date. If it is triggered on 3 pm today, it is likley to be triggerd on 3pm next year too.